# JWT and API Key on same api route?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, api-key

I'm working on a project where I've got an API that will be consumed by a mobile application and other third party APIs. Problem is that there are routes that are used by both type of users (mobile and third party) and I couldn't find yet a proper way to integrate those two types of authentication (JWT token and api key).

My questions are:

1. Is it a good approach to have same route consumed like explained above?
2. Does someone have a good example/read over this?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like it's unclear who you want your API's consumer to be.
If the mobile application consuming you is yours then this api is an internal/private api, not a public one. JWT are kinda made for this type of use case.

If on the other want you want your API to be consumed using a api key then the API is either public or premium (people have to pay to use, or it has a throttle limit etc, even though that's not always true)

One of the things you can do is to have two APIs, one being consumed using the JWT for my mobile app without any rps limit etc, and a public one which is using an api key. The advantage is not only the authentication difference but also that you can apply different policies for consumption.

If on the other hand you want your consumers to consume the data in the same way for both auth methods then you can have two types of authentication. You would have to write custom middleware that essentially checks weather someone us using a bearer token or and api key to authenticate and use the appropriate authentication mechanism.

Comment: It's more like a premium API (B2B) and I'm looking into building that middleware that you're mentioning, but I don't find an example on this in order to be sure that I go in the right direction. Do you know some example or a good read about this?

Comment: This documentation link explains exactly how AuthorizationHandlers work, which is something you can use to achieve this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies

Comment: will look into that on Monday and come back with updates. I think the problem with this approach is that the backend is supporting already multiple authentication methods based on jwt, but I'll get all the details and come back with them.